# Variable global a modo de sesión de usuario en angularjs (Controller)

Tags: angularjs

estoy creando una aplicación web sobre unos cursos en la que el necesito guardar un campo (dato del nombre o nif por ejemplo) a lo largo de la sesión del usuario que se loguea, para luego en otra parte cuando el usuario finaliza el curso y piche sobre el botón "Aceptar", se guarde el progreso en la base de datos.

Si le solicito al usuario previamente a que pulse sobre "Aceptar" el campo, ya lo recojo y lo trato en la función del controlador de ModificarProgreso, esto sí me funciona, pero necesito no pedir ese campo al usuario. Es decir, que solamente metiendo su nombre una vez en el login, ya pueda tratar esa variable a lo largo de la aplicación.

En al controlador tengo, en este caso, esta función que recoge el nif en el login:

```
var app = angular.module('gestionUsuarioCurso');    
app.controller('usuariosCursoController',function($scope,$http,usuariosCursoService){

    gestionUsuarioCurso = this;    
    gestionUsuarioCurso.progresoUsuario;    
    gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario;   
    gestionUsuarioCurso.curso;    
    gestionUsuarioCurso.usuarios = [];
    gestionUsuarioCurso.status;    
    this.progresoUsuario = 0;

    this.selectProgreso = function (){

        return this.progresoUsuario;

    };   

    $scope.LoginUsuario = function(){

        usuariosCursoService.loginUser($scope.nif,$scope.password).then(function(usuario){

           gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario = usuario;    
           //gestionUsuarioCurso.nif = $scope.nif;
           //console.log(gestionUsuarioCurso.nif);
        });
    }
```

..................

Con el $scope.nif obtengo el nif y puedo tratarlo en esa función, pero si lo quiero ahora usar en esta otra funcion de ModificarProgreso, me aparece por la consola de depuración (f12 en chrome) undefined ese campo.

EL metodo showUser (dentro de ModificarProgreso) intenta buscar un usuario en la bbdd con el campo nif, en este caso se lo pasa el usuario a mano.
...............

```
$scope.ModificarProgreso = function(temaFinalizado){

    //console.log($scope.nif);  
    usuariosCursoService.showUser($scope.nif).then(function(usuario) {                                                        
        console.log($scope.nif);
        gestionUsuarioCurso.usuario = usuario;
    });
}
```

He intentado crear una variable global como las del inicio del controller para que vaya "viajando" el dato por las páginas pero no me funciona.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es guardar el nif creo que el `value provider` podría valerte:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe

Con esto puedes crear una variable como en el ejemplo que contenga el nif para luego inyectarla en los controladores de angular que quieras.
Pero si quieres hacer algo más complejo (o piensas que tu aplicación puede crecer) te recomiendo que implementes Redux en ella.

https://redux.js.org/

Esta librería te permite tener el estado de la aplicación siempre disponible y actualizado en cualquier parte. La curva de aprendizaje puede ser algo dura, pero merece la pena.